# CodeIgniter Transaction not responding

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter transaction and making it work. However, when executing nothings happening. This is my code:

```
public function submit($data){

    $to_return = true;
            $this->db->trans_begin();

            $this->insert_arrest_details($data);
            $this->insert_arresting_officers($data);
            $folders = $this->insert_violators($data);  
            $this->insert_arrest_booking_form($data);           
            $this->insert_inventory(json_decode($data['inventory']));
            $this->insert_items(json_decode($data['items']));   
            $this->insert_violator_items(json_decode($data['items']));  

            if($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE){
                $to_return = $this->return_error_message();
            }else{  
                $img_success = $this->move_violators_images($folders);
                $img_success = $this->move_items_images(json_decode($data['inventory']));
                $this->db->trans_commit();
            }       
            return $to_return;
        }
```

It seems that my code is doing nothing when I checked my network i got nothing in response. Even errors were not present.

What seems to be the problem? If this is transaction lock out it should prompt me after 50 seconds (I set this on config), but its not.

Your responses will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You were using `$this->insert_arrest_details($data);` are these functions are within same page or another one

Comment: on the same file sir. If you wish, i can edit my question and paste all my functions.

Comment: should I restart my xampp or pc? Maybe there's a thread causing the problem.

Comment: Post your whole code

Comment: $this->db->trans_complete(); ?

Comment: you should use $this->db->trans_complete() in place of $this->db->trans_commit();

Comment: @RajeshK  No. as far as i understand,  $this->db->trans_complete() **before** $this->db->trans_status()

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the transaction and then return the status.

```
    $this->db->trans_start();

    /*your code here*/

    $this->db->trans_complete();    

    return $this->db->trans_status();
```